# Build an visitcounter for subdomains magento

Tags: magento

I know it sounds stupid but I have some magento storeviews with different subdomains. It 100% identical content because its for an multilevelmarketing company. Know I need to track the clicks and visits for every single subdomain. I didn't figured out if it's possible to do it with google analytics. This is by the way not my favorite because I wanne make the statistics look like selfmade.

I was thinking about editing the index.php of magento to figure out which store-code is loaded and than to save it in a database with IP-adress and time. After all I would use a cronejob to  clean up the database after a while.

Would you give me some tips for things I should take care of? Because I never did something like a visitor counter.

Comment: Take a look @ log_visitor, log_visitor_*, log_url and log_url_* db table, should contain all the info you needed

Comment: +1 on log_* tables; also, of course you can (and should) do this with GA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these database tables

```
log_visitor
log_visitor_*
log_url
log_url_*
log_*
```

Comment: this is great. But I have one problem. The log_summery has no entry. What do I have to do, for getting magento to create a log_summery???

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the data out of the log_summery table. But the table is allways empty. I have activated in the backend to create a log. But for me it seems he is creating logfiles and not creating databaseentries.

Comment: I dont think magento is currently using that table (mine is also empty). You can join log_visitor and log_visitor_info on (key) visitor_id for that info. If you need url info then join log_url and log_url_info on (key) visitor_id and url_id